# How do I retrieve the value in a Named range that matches part of a Cell Text?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**I need a formula that can help search the values in the named Range against the Cell value and return the matching text.** Please note that the matching text could start at any index of the Cell value.

**I have a named Range (RNG) containing values {ABC,DEF,GHI} and the cells (A2 & A3) contains the Text "TEST_DEF_XXX", "THIS STRING CONTAINS DEF".  The formula must be able to retrieve DEF as a result both the cases.**

I have tried **SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(RNG,A2)))**, but it returns only TRUE or FALSE and not the matching text. Can someone help please?

Comment: If you have Office 365, try `FILTER()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`=LOOKUP(1,0/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(RNG,A2)),RNG)`

Comment: Great. It will return the first occurrence of any of the 'range substrings' in the string. If the string is `TEST_DEF_ABC`, it will return `DEF`. Is there an easy way to return the first found (looking at the range) 'substring' (`ABC`)?

Comment: Actually it returns the last occurring string from RNG which is found.

Comment: You're right, sorry. What I mean is can this `{=INDEX(RNG,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(RNG,A2)),0))}` be written by using `LOOKUP`?

Comment: Not so easily, no. But I see nothing wrong with your construction. Unless you've fallen foul of the fear-mongering avoid-array-formulas sect? If so, you should know that, required keystroke combination aside, the LOOKUP construction I give is no less an array formula than that which you give using INDEX/MATCH.

Comment: You got me there. Thanks for the response.